# Get information about all exceptions in the application

Tags: java, android

I writing an error log.

You should be aware of any exceptions that occurred while the application was running.

In addition to preserving the text of `e.getMessage()` with each exception, are there other ways to implement it?

Comment: Are you talking about uncaught exceptions or caught ones?

Comment: I'm talking about all the exceptions.

Comment: Well, for exceptions that you are already catching you'll probably need to log it yourself. For uncaught ones however, you can create a global exception Handler. Have a look at `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Comment: Can you describe how it works or give an example of a global exception handler?

Comment: I overlooked that your question was for android specifically. You should do what Tamir said in the answer. It will help you and save you some time in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [connect your app to firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and use the [crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) - the crash reporter of firebase.
It will alert you every time your app will crash(from exceptions for example), you can later see those crashes for every phone that has the app installed.